# AngularJS UI-Router Multilingual website

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multilingual, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to build multilingual website in **AngularJS**. Delivering proper translation in templates seems pretty straightforward but I'm stuck on implementing proper **multilingual routes** using UI-Router. I couldn't have found any suitable examples.

It has to scale easily while adding new languages. Example of routes structure for two languages is:

```
/en
/en/products
/en/products/green-category
/en/products/green-category/green-product-1

/cs
/cs/produkty
/cs/produkty/zelena-kategorie
/cs/produkty/zelena-kategorie/zeleny-produkt-1
```

Product categories are hard-coded, products are loaded from database.

I'm trying something like this (leaving out product categories since they are similar to 'products', just one level deeper in hierarchy):

```
$stateProvider.state('product', {
    url: '/{lang:' + Translate.getLangs() + '}/{products:' + Translate.getRouteVariants('products') + '}/{productSlug}',
    templateUrl: 'app/product.html',
    resolve: {
        product : function($stateParams){
            return Data.products.get( Data.products.deslug($stateParams.productSlug, $stateParams.lang), $stateParams.lang );
        }
    }
});
```

And in controller / template:

```
$scope.productLink = function(id) {
    return {
        lang:$rootScope.lang,
        products:Translate.getRoute('products', $rootScope.lang),
        productSlug:Data.products.slug(1, $rootScope.lang)
    };
}

<a ui-sref="product(productLink(1))">Green product 1</a>
```

Where

```
Translate, Data are providers
Translate.getLangs() -> 'en|cs'
Translate.getRoute('products', lang) -> 'products' or 'produkty' based on lang
Translate.getRouteVariants('products') -> 'products|produkty'

Data.products.slug(productId, lang) -> returns productSlug from model
Data.products.deslug(productSlug, lang) -> returns productId from model
Data.products.get(productId, lang) -> loads data
```

Handling with current language should be done better (probably in Translate provider).

Routes shouldn't match cross-lang urls such as '/en/produkty'. Big problem.
/edit: I probably could use $stateChangeStart, check whether all parametres are in one language and if not, redirect to top-level state.

And this whole solution doesn't seem way too elegant (since I'm begginer with Angular) so if anyone can provide any insights on this subject, I'll be glad.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First I would like to advise about one particular point about displaying multi-lingual content  if your presentation is going to be same irrespective of language and locale. And that is...

**You do not want to repeat your view/presentation code.**

Your code could duplicate quite a lot and cause you some problem.

However if you really want to have them separate template I am thinking that your following line may have problem;-

```
url: '/{lang:' + Translate.getLangs() + '}/{products:' + Translate.getRouteVariants('products') + '}/{productSlug}',
```

If you use curly brace approach the text after `:` is actually a regular expression.
So you can't just return the getLangs() as `'en|ch'` it should be something like

```
'[a-z][a-z]{en|ch}'
```

(I have not tested but should work.)

Comment: Yes, I probably should move states definitions and template link parametres together into one global provider which will be used to feed $stateProvider and custom directive.